# format money in PHP so it is "$xxx.xx USD"

Tags: php, currency

I'm trying to use `money_format` in PHP to get this result: `$100,000.00 USD` if that is possible.

Here is what I have:

```
$cost = 100000;
$usd = money_format('%i', $cost);
```

This is what I get:

```
USD 100,000.00
```

What I would like is:

```
$100,000.00 USD
```

I may be adding other currencies later, so if the solution breaks the general utility and l10n of `money_format` then I won't use it and will just use the default value.

Comment: It is redundant to use a dollar sign ($) and USD, just one of them is enough to indicate currency.

Comment: If you want to deviate from the standard monetary format PHP uses, then you can use `money_format('%n USD', $cost)` and you may have to check the locale setting if you are wanting to make it work across several currencies. If you are deviating from the standard output of PHP for US currency, you might end up deviating for other currencies as well.

Comment: **$US** always made the most sense to me and i always want it in front

Comment: @Gustek Actually that is not always true. The ($) sign is not unique to the US Dollar. It is used in many different currencies: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i prefer number_format()

```
$usd =  '$'.number_format($number, 2, '.', ',').' USD';
```

Comment: the php developers love functions, there are many that do the same thing - but seriously money_format() has it s place as it uses the locale. mine hard codes that

Comment: if you wrote a payment scrip for sale, you wouldn't want to hard code the format for every country that might buy it. money_format solves that

Comment: You can set the local for the the whole webapp at once. Then money_format will change accordingly.  Otherwise, with anything hardcoded you will need to track it and set it yourself... But yes they love functions :-)